# Replacing phone line and modems with a pair of serial device servers

Tags: internet, modem, serial

I have a pair of legacy applications that connect to each other through a phone line by use of external serial modems. I want to replace the telephone line with an Internet connection. The objective is to have a hardware device on each end connected to the computer exactly as the modem was, with this device behaving just like a modem (AT commands, etc.). Preferably, the devices should establish a connection when the modem would dial and drop the connection when the modem would hang up, as opposed to being an "always on" connection.

Quick diagram:

```
PC ---[RS-232]--- device server --- Internet --- device server ---[RS-232]--- PC
```

I found a few products:

- [SDS1101](http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/external-device-servers/securebox-sds1101.html) by Lantronix
- [PortServer TS](http://www.digi.com/products/serialservers/portserverts.jsp#specs) by Digi

Both advertise a 'modem emulation' feature, which is what I want, but I thought I'd ask someone who may have used these devices in the past.

Will these devices accomplish what I have to do? Does anyone have any suggestions for other products designed for this kind of thing?

I sincerely thank everyone for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EtherPath® SS-1R Single Port Serial Server "Ethernet Modem" by DCB (Data Comm For Business, Inc.)
http://www.dcbnet.com/datasheet/ss1ds.html

I have experience with these in the field (hundereds) for 6+ years and not one has ever failed.  We have not used their "EtherModem" mode but if the quality of that holds up like everything else in this device then it is worth a look.

I do not know or work for them, just a happy customer.